# pnpm node-linker in workspace

Tags: pnpm, pnpm-workspace

with #pnpm, when using react-native or Expo, as far as I know, we have to use `node-linker=hoisted`.

My problem is that I have a workspace with multiple packages and I'd like to activate this mode only on react-native package.

But I can't figure out how to have this mode only for a specific package of the workspace : when setting this in a .npmrc of the package, it is not used. When set in a .npmrc at the root of the project, all dependencies of all packages are hoisted in the root's node-module directory.

I'm not sure it is possible but in case ...

thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4):

It is not possible. You can set it only in the root `.npmrc` (in the same directory where `pnpm-workspace.yaml` is) and it will be applied to all projects in that workspace.

But don't be afraid to use it for all projects. pnpm will still be fast and disk space efficient. And to solve the phantom dependencies issues, you may configure the [import/no-extraneous-dependencies](https://github.com/import-js/eslint-plugin-import/blob/main/docs/rules/no-extraneous-dependencies.md) rule of ESLint's [import plugin](https://github.com/import-js/eslint-plugin-import).